# Combo box options to hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please note that i have the following two set of codes which does different functions

1. Drop down list set to hyperlink
2. Combo box (textbox as well as dropdown) which selects the option but no hyperlink

Now: I want to combine these functions

### My first set of code:

---

```
<select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')">
        <option value="Select City">Select City</option>
        <option value="http://www.18flats.com/city/mumbai/">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="http://www.18flats.com/city/pune/">Pune</option>
        <option value="http://www.18flats.com/city/bangalore/">Bangalore</option>
        <option value="http://www.18flats.com/city/delhi/">Delhi</option>
</select>
```

### My second set of code:

---

```
 <script>
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
_create: function() {
this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox" )
.insertAfter( this.element );
this.element.hide();
this._createAutocomplete();
this._createShowAllButton();
},
_createAutocomplete: function() {
var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
this.input = $( "<input>" )
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.val( value )
.attr( "title", "" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
.autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 0,
source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
})
.tooltip({
tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
});
this._on( this.input, {
autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
ui.item.option.selected = true;
this._trigger( "select", event, {
item: ui.item.option
});
},
autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
},
_createShowAllButton: function() {
var input = this.input,
wasOpen = false;
$( "<a>" )
.attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
.attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
.tooltip()
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.button({
icons: {
primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
},
text: false
})
.removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
.mousedown(function() {
wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
})
.click(function() {
input.focus();
// Close if already visible
if ( wasOpen ) {
return;
}
// Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
});
},
_source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
var text = $( this ).text();
if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
return {
label: text,
value: text,
option: this
};
}) );
},
_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
// Selected an item, nothing to do
if ( ui.item ) {
return;
}
// Search for a match (case-insensitive)
var value = this.input.val(),
valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
valid = false;
this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
this.selected = valid = true;
return false;
}
});
// Found a match, nothing to do
if ( valid ) {
return;
}
// Remove invalid value
this.input
.val( "" )
.attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
.tooltip( "open" );
this.element.val( "" );
this._delay(function() {
this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
}, 2500 );
this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
},
_destroy: function() {
this.wrapper.remove();
this.element.show();
}
});
})( jQuery );
$(function() {
$( "#combobox" ).combobox();
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
$( "#combobox" ).toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
<select id="combobox">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
<option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
<option value="Asp">Asp</option>
<option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="C++">C++</option>
<option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
<option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
<option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
<option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
<option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
<option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
<option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
<option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
<option value="Scala">Scala</option>
<option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
</div>
<button id="toggle">Show underlying select</button>
```

Second set can be seen in live [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Forget the toggle button, I'm not interested in that! What i want is redirection/hyperlink directly to the page which are linked in the value!

Another option that I will be v.helpful with is Go button, when clicked on GO should redirect me to that page(hyperlink)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide working fiddle

Comment: first set of code does not require fiddle and second set can be seen in live jQuery Website [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)